# I am not evil but the saint one - What am I?

Tags: riddle

You might think I can be anything and voted too broad;
no two, but only one will fit in me.

I am used in many a story for sins;
yet I am not evil but the saint one.

Sing, you will not hear but see me in many tones;
Rearranged, same as in your notes.

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's...

> STONE.

no two, but only one will fit in me.

> stONE

I am used in many story for sins;

> being stoned as punishment

yet I am not evil but the saint one.

> St. One

Sing, you will not hear but see me in many tones;
Rearranged, same as in your notes.

> Both anagrams of "stone"

Comment: That is it!  Nicely Done!